# C# Using WebClient & a Timer Together To Actively Display Updated Data

Tags: c#, html, timer, webclient

I have a site that is extremely basic and will only ever consist of a single integer.

However the integer will actively change, I want to add onto my existing application to display what this integer is in real time.

-I've tried using a Timer and WebClient however if I put the code under InitializeComponent() the form will never load.

-Also if I put the code in Form1_Load the form will never load.

-I was successful in getting the number to display in real time by putting the code under a button_click event, but I want this code to begin as soon as the form load.

-Also when the button was first clicked the first timer sequence the label would display lat (unsure what this means)

-After the button was pressed and the timer loop began the app breaks, the number will update properly, but you cannot use any other functionality of the app, you can not move the window, you cannot close the app, etc..

```
    private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Timer timer = (Timer)sender;
        this.Visible = false;
        timer.Stop();
        this.Visible = true;
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int c = 5;
        while (c == 5)
        {
            using (var client = new WebClient())
            {
                var s = client.DownloadString(@"myURL.html");
                var htmldoc2 = (IHTMLDocument2)new HTMLDocument();
                htmldoc2.write(s);
                var plainText = htmldoc2.body.outerText;
                label1.Text = plainText;
                System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
                timer.Interval = 5000;
                timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
                timer.Start();
            }
        }
      }
```

Please help me no clue what I am doing wrong here

Comment: That is most likely happening because you are occupying the single thread that is already running (that infinite loop wont let anything else to run unless kicked within another thread). You most likely will need to implement async or you could just run your code with Task.StartNew().

Answer (score -1):

I managed to fix my issue by using the following code if anyone ever has a similar question:

```
    private void test()
    {
        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            var s = client.DownloadString(@"myURL.html");
            var htmldoc2 = (IHTMLDocument2)new HTMLDocument();
            htmldoc2.write(s);
            var plainText = htmldoc2.body.outerText;
            label1.Text = plainText;
        }
    }
    int i = 1;
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        i += 1;
        if (i >= 199)
        {
            i = 1;
            timer1.Stop();
            timer1.Start();
        }
        test();
    }
```

timer1 was added to the winform from the toolbox, and is set to enabled with an interval of 200